# Add an overall average row to Report Builder report

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services, report, reportbuilder3.0

I need help creating an overall average in Report Builder 3.0. I have a query that returns data in the following format:

```
Major       Num Of Students     Max GPA     Min GPA     Avg GPA
----------  ------------------  ----------  ----------  -----------
Accounting  89                  4.0         2.3         3.68
Business    107                 4.0         2.13        3.23
CIS         85                  3.98        2.53        3.75
```

I added a total row in Report Builder that shows the sum number of students, overall Max GPA, and overall Min GPA. But I can't simply run the `Avg` function on the Avg GPA column, as it needs to take into account the number of students for an overall average. I believe that I need to do something like the following (in pseudocode):

```
foreach ( row in rows ) {
    totalGpa      += row.numOfStudents * row.avgGpa
    totalStudents += row.numOfStudents
}

overallAvgGpa = totalGpa / totalStudents
```

Does anyone know how I could do this in my report?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case you need weighted average here, something like this in the Total row:

```
=Sum(Fields!numOfStudents.Value * Fields!avgGpa.Value)
  / Sum(Fields!numOfStudents.Value)
```

You can see I'm creating the expression `Fields!numOfStudents.Value * Fields!avgGpa.Value` for each row, summing that, then dividing by the total students.

In your case this would give `(89 * 3.68 + 107 * 3.23 + 85 * 3.75) / (89 + 107 + 85)`, i.e. `3.53`, which seems about correct.

Comment: Worked perfectly. Thank you for your help, Ian.